Can you link physics properties between different objects?
I'm testing some Rigid Body physics for a lot of objects. I want to test the different properties of the rigid body, but I don't want to have to change the values for every object individually. Is there a way to link the physics properties between all of them so they all change simultaneously?

An alternative, but laborious to set up is to RMB-context menu over your primary object, "Copy as New Driver", and then over each objects same property. RMB-context Paste as new Driver.  This for each property of interest.  Admittedly very laborious.

You can simply select multiple objects, go to the physics tab, enter any value you want, and then hold the Alt key and press Enter"

@Dgc But note: this way objects change by the same "offset", not to the same value. When all objects have the same values, you won't notice a difference. But let's say you have one rigid body with a mass of 5 kg and one one with 10 kg and you want them both to be 15 kg. If you change the 5 to 15 kg and press alt+return, the second will have a mass of 20 kg, not 15. Because to get the first to 15, you increased by 10. The second has 10 kg, so 10 + 10 = 20. If you change the 10 kg to 15, the 5 kg will become 5 + 5 = 10 kg.

@Dgc If you want to change the values on multiple objects to be all the same no matter what their initial values are before changing, then you have to hold the Alt key when clicking into a value field before changing the value. Then you can afterwards even press Return without Alt key to confirm the new value.

That is also very useful to know, thanks a lot!

@Dgc Yeah, actually there is already a duplicate question where I explained the different variations in detail in my answer.
